# are there any downsides to a full load-strategy for datamarts...?

Tags: etl, datamart

... apart from the performance impact?

In our situation, the data volumes will be overseeable, the complexity may not.

Background:
I have experienced a project where the datamarts were fully loaded each day.
This simplified the ETL because no delta processing needed to be done. For the same reason, performance was also acceptable. However I am not sure if this scenario is always usable, if there are downsides e.g. when an end user tells us the data is 'wrong' since 4 days - it would be difficult to trace that back.

Thanks for your input

Comment: Please rephrase the question. Questions with "Please provide a link" are off-topic: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. "

Comment: thanks, I changed it. I just wanted to make the question answerable - that's why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the business requirements, it is a perfectly acceptable strategy.

One thing you will lose is the ability to show the history of slowly changing dimensions. If this is not important to your business, don't worry about it.

At [Ajilius](http://ajilius.com) we have a customer in the high fashion industry who reloads their data warehouse on an hourly basis. This is because of the need to show near real-time visualisation of their product planning cycle, which is seasonal, any data can change at any time, and has no long term history requirement.

A more common case is where there is no change data capture capability in the source DBMS. You'll often see full reloads of facts and dimensions in this circumstance. Facts are less likely - you usually have a date or timestamp to govern an extract - but full dimension reloads happen quite often.